# My mail DKIM-Signature creates an email address out of thin air

Tags: java, email, smtp, mandrill, dkim

I use mandrill to send emails created using javamail. When I try to send an email from our application using the from address of our users, the DKIM-Signature contains an email address we never assigned and which does not exists. When I sent this email without using mandrill, the mail does not get altered.

The problem is that when we sent an email from our application which uses a SKIM signature for **ourdomain.com** and we send an email for a user on a different domain **user_domain.com**, the from and sender headers get set as folows:

```
From: Joost Schouten <joost@user_omain.com>
Sender: Joost Schouten <joost@ourdomain.com>
```

The Sender header is never set by us, nor does the email address exist and unfortunately some mail clients use this address to reply to. It is a combination of the from email part without the domain and the DKIM signed domain. I have no clue why this is happening and how to stop it from happening.

The DKIM-Signature also mentions this non existing address so I'm assuming that might be the cause. Unfortunately all the DKIM documentation is somewhat lost on me so I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

**This is the complete mail:**

```
Delivered-To: info@ourdomain.com
Received: by 10.129.137.131 with SMTP id z125csp831548ywf;
        Thu, 2 Jul 2015 13:02:36 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.170.121.210 with SMTP id n201mr40312958ykb.97.1435867356185;
        Thu, 02 Jul 2015 13:02:36 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <bounce-md_30191264.559598db.v1-0709e43ec6fc4aaaa2eaa4b9a07c553a@mandrillapp.com>
Received: from mail133-7.atl131.mandrillapp.com (mail133-7.atl131.mandrillapp.com. [198.2.133.7])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 13si4642642ykz.152.2015.07.02.13.02.35
        for <info@ourdomain.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 02 Jul 2015 13:02:36 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounce-md_30191264.559598db.v1-0709e43ec6fc4aaaa2eaa4b9a07c553a@mandrillapp.com designates 198.2.133.7 as permitted sender) client-ip=198.2.133.7;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounce-md_30191264.559598db.v1-0709e43ec6fc4aaaa2eaa4b9a07c553a@mandrillapp.com designates 198.2.133.7 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=bounce-md_30191264.559598db.v1-0709e43ec6fc4aaaa2eaa4b9a07c553a@mandrillapp.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@ourdomain.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mandrillapp.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mandrill; d=ourdomain.com;
 h=From:Sender:Subject:To:Message-Id:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=joost@ourdomain.com;
 bh=b4xtohIO7sTTZ/geyDmOzKRydBw=;
 b=A1snz1SKxbRxJobxUqb5cxn2+s+Rj9osVXk61sJVNNc1VoVVmy7jh471byqGm7nYXGPqsL361zOE
   OPXxrdS+Zfr0Wrlhft5q6kgaJCy7xodtICXGGi6a/8xgUZ0Ko/JzWB2SI9Nqe6sMGwg5ecZDDxnt
   9u+cBHKpKBN4JY2pjEs=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=mandrill; d=ourdomain.com;
 b=FJ6zXTYOnZY/RN7okxXDpl5sNL0ysjDQfXixD8vfLk7nvpEB2Y7vUBe7EKbC0dLuHRtLSullN9Eg
   ARddkGh81Mes/ergpfyy/epulj745nOfPR8h4cQsu6dhe2p8xHA3H8AJDf2XTX8SnspuZrBgrcmU
   gXI1cSTr/QTAz6emAbE=;
Received: from pmta02.mandrill.prod.atl01.rsglab.com (127.0.0.1) by mail133-7.atl131.mandrillapp.com id himcdo1sar88 for <info@ourdomain.com>; Thu, 2 Jul 2015 20:02:35 +0000 (envelope-from <bounce-md_30191264.559598db.v1-0709e43ec6fc4aaaa2eaa4b9a07c553a@mandrillapp.com>)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mandrillapp.com; 
 i=@mandrillapp.com; q=dns/txt; s=mandrill; t=1435867355; h=From : 
 Sender : Subject : To : Message-Id : Date : MIME-Version : Content-Type 
 : From : Subject : Date : X-Mandrill-User : List-Unsubscribe; 
 bh=+XtZFak4OUf8qSxm1jSRVqiU996OawoBIDsFv7gsDOM=; 
 b=UTTtcU5XeoBFrCe4v/wpBY02o5aZYRbPKWCpiKxYrrOsuqe+PqizEADb8qqkPqDKteiSOK
 K6Gz58xX1DsDGm7O6g85OX4Rqi5edA3YFVgGE4VWG7q6TxKleXsb95TXjqh/pXbUpVqH+oWn
 wnNT3PgznJFhgY0lz1njBZqvEREpg=
From: Joost Schouten <joost@user_domain.com>
Sender: Joost Schouten <joost@ourdomain.com>
Subject: Subject
Return-Path: <bounce-md_30191264.559598db.v1-0709e43ec6fc4aaaa2eaa4b9a07c553a@mandrillapp.com>
Received: from [95.85.39.219] by mandrillapp.com id 0709e43ec6fc4aaaa2eaa4b9a07c553a; Thu, 02 Jul 2015 20:02:35 +0000
X-Mailer: Mailer name
To: Receiver <info@ourdomain.com>
Message-Id: <328629681.01435867315102.JavaMail.tomcat7@www>
X-Report-Abuse: Please forward a copy of this message, including all headers, to abuse@mandrill.com
X-Report-Abuse: You can also report abuse here: http://mandrillapp.com/contact/abuse?id=30191264.0709e43ec6fc4aaaa2eaa4b9a07c553a
X-Mandrill-User: md_30191264
Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 20:02:35 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_av-RYsOAD_G5IlIUfcO9tyvnQ"

--_av-RYsOAD_G5IlIUfcO9tyvnQ
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

PLAIN TEXT CONTENT

--_av-RYsOAD_G5IlIUfcO9tyvnQ
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><head><title></title></head><body> THE HTML CONTENT</body></html>
--_av-RYsOAD_G5IlIUfcO9tyvnQ--
```

**(EDIT - added the java code)** My mail sending code (Simplified)

```
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, false);                       helper.getMimeMessage().setSubject(emailMessage.getSubject(), defaultCharSet);

helper.addTo(new InternetAddress("some@receiver.com", "Rex receiver"));             
helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress("joost@user_domain.com", "Joost Schouten"));

//commenting this next line out does not change anything
helper.getMimeMessage().setSender("no-reply@ourdomain.com");

helper.setText(htmlContentVar, true);
helper.getMimeMessage().addHeader("X-Mailer", xMailer);
helper.getMimeMessage().addHeader("X-MC-SigningDomain", "ourdomain.com");
helper.getMimeMessage().addHeader("X-MC-AutoText", "true");
helper.getMimeMessage().addHeader("X-MC-Track", "opens,clicks");
helper.getMimeMessage().addHeader("X-MC-Tags", emailMessage.getTags());

javaMailSender.send(helper.getMimeMessage());
```

Comment: Can you give us a code sample that can reproduce the error?  Without that we would only be guessing at where the issue is.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I just added the javacode. Unfortunately my application creates the email exactly like i'd like it to. It's when I route the email though mandrill that the header get's added/changed.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf The issue lies with Mandrill, see my answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with Mandrill as they add the `Sender` header to ensure it is on the domain signing the email. The obvious problem here being that they even override the Sender header when I specify it myself on our own domain. Currently we have explicitly added the `Reply-to` header as well as the `From` header to invite as many email clients as possible to use those addresses vs. the `Sender` option. This does seem to help but we are not fully sure this will solve the reply address issue for all email clients.

I hope this will save someone from pulling out their hair trying to figure out what's going on. This is mandrill's their full answer:

> Thanks for reaching out. Mandrill adds the Sender: header to your
>   message headers to support signing and authenticating your emails when
>   the sending domain does not have SPF and DKIM records. A few email
>   clients (but not all) choose to display the address from this header
>   rather than the address in the From: header.
>
> Mandrill adds a Sender header to all emails that are sent from a
>   domain that doesn't have SPF and DKIM set up. And we construct the
>   Sender header address by combining the local portion of the From
>   address (everything before the @ symbol) with the singing domain. In
>   many cases, this can create an address that doesn't actually exist —
>   as you've pointed out — but generally this only impacts the display of
>   those emails and not actually email replies. You should still be able
>   to reply to the email and have the original From: or Reply-To: address
>   be used as the recipient of your response rather than the constructed
>   sender header which doesn't exist.
>
> We are looking at ways we may be able to update how we construct that
>   header to avoid confusion, but I don't have an ETA I can offer just
>   yet for when those changes might be available.
>
> I hope this information was helpful. Let us know if you have any
>   further questions.